# Python: Specify end-of-line format for reading files

Tags: python, file-io, end-of-line

I'm writing a Python script which processes a text file. I expect to process files generated from different people, working under different operating systems. Is there a nice way to figure out which OS created the text file, and specify the end-of-line convention to make parsing line-by-line trivial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use universal newline mode when opening the file.

```
with open('input.txt', 'rU') as fp:
  for line in fp:
    print line
```

Answer (score 2):

[`splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) handles various line terminators:

```
>>> 'foo\nbar'.splitlines()
['foo', 'bar']
>>> 'foo\rbar'.splitlines()
['foo', 'bar']
>>> 'foo\r\nbar'.splitlines()
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about ending white space then:

```
for line in [l.rstrip() for l in open('test.py').read().split('\n')]:
    print line
```

'\n' will take care of Linux / Mac and rstrip will eat up any '\r' from Windows.

Comment: This gives me an error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: Mauahah got it! I had to change split('\n') to split('\r') though. Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh darn, there's one more thing... I've got to do something special with the 1st line of the file, then process the rest...

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `file.readlines()`, which returns a list containing the lines in the file.

```
lines = open('info.txt').readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

See the documentation on [Python file objects](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).